# iOS 7 CRUD Application - Interface to input data

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7, crud

guys!

I've been studying iOS development for a few days, and I wanted to create a CRUD application to make sure I am understanding the concepts.

Well, I wanted to create a interface to input data similar to the Phone app, where user can insert a new contact. In my understanding, it seems to be a table view. However, every tutorial I find about table views are related to displaying data and not inputing it. Am I right?

I'm not expecting any code sample or anything like that, I just want to know how can I provide a good experience similar to the one in Phone App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Contacts app on the iPhone is built on `UITableView`s. Apple does not provide any guideline for your question. Use them or don't, it's up to you.

It might be quicker though to use a `UITableView` in your case, as you may need to present/edit much information and the scrolling would already be handled by the system.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find anything in Apple's guidelines. But anyway, thanks for your fast response.

Best regards.